# OWSLib - ValueError: All strings must be XML compatible: Unicode or ASCII

Tags: python, geonetwork, encoding, owslib

I try to use OWSLib to search metadata in GeoNetwork, and I have problems when the string contains non-ASCII characters.

```
geonetwork = 'http://geonetwork-mshe.univ-fcomte.fr:8080/geonetwork/srv/fre/csw' 
from owslib.csw import CatalogueServiceWeb
csw = CatalogueServiceWeb(geonetwork)
```

1) ASCII string. It is OK.

```
myquery = PropertyIsEqualTo('csw:AnyText', 'africa') 
csw.getrecords2(constraints=[myquery], maxrecords=20) 
csw.results
```

> {'matches': 1, 'nextrecord': 0, 'returned': 1}

2) string with accents

```
myquery = PropertyIsEqualTo('csw:AnyText', 'été') 
csw.getrecords2(constraints=[myquery], maxrecords=20)
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/owslib/csw.py", line 355, in getrecords2
    node2.append(flt.setConstraintList(constraints))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/owslib/fes.py", line 151, in setConstraintList
    flt = self.setConstraint(constraints[0])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/owslib/fes.py", line 120, in setConstraint
    self._root.append(constraint.toXML())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/owslib/fes.py", line 280, in toXML
    etree.SubElement(node0, util.nspath_eval('ogc:Literal', namespaces)).text = self.literal
  File "src/lxml/lxml.etree.pyx", line 1031, in lxml.etree._Element.text.__set__ (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:55347)
  File "src/lxml/apihelpers.pxi", line 711, in lxml.etree._setNodeText (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:24667)
  File "src/lxml/apihelpers.pxi", line 699, in lxml.etree._createTextNode (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:24516)
  File "src/lxml/apihelpers.pxi", line 1439, in lxml.etree._utf8 (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:32441)
ValueError: All strings must be XML compatible: Unicode or ASCII, no NULL bytes or control characters
```

I tried to use `&eacute;` instead of é, but without success...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

You should replace :

```
myquery = PropertyIsEqualTo('csw:AnyText', 'été')
```

with:

```
myquery = PropertyIsEqualTo('csw:AnyText', u'été')
```

The prefix indicates a unicode string : [3.1.3. Unicode Strings](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html#unicode-strings)